# C++ protobuf, ZMQ. Functions of client-server interface

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, protocol-buffers, zeromq

While I doing program server-client on C++, using ZMQ and protobufs from Google,  touched functions related with variance of types.

Problem: functions `ParseFromString` and `SerializeToString` use string type as parameter, but I need write program using `zmq::message_t`  such as a parameter.

```
Proto file:
package core;
{ message Request
required uint32 id=1;
required uint32 class_id=2;
...}

zmq::message_t msg; // beginning
core::Request reqt;
…
socket.recv(&msg) ;// receiving messgae, socket.recv(reqt) doesn't work
ParseFromString (msg); //serialization to structure doesn’t work
```

Program is a client-server execution using sockets
Need to coordinate variables string type and message between each other.
Functions ParseFromString() и SerializeToString().
В Python все просто: 
    socket.send(reqt.SerializeToString()) и
    class_id=reqt.ParseFromString(socket.recv)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ParseFromArray()`:

```
reqt.ParseFromArray(msg.data(), msg.size());
```

On the serializing side, use `ByteSize()` to get the size of the protobuf message, allocate space for it, then `SerializeToArray()` to write the bytes into the space.

Full documentation on these methods and others can be found at:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite

Answer (score 0):

```
(&string_obj) != string_obj.c_str()
```

https://github.com/junhyeokahn/zmq-protobuf/blob/master/cpp-py/publisher.cpp

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.